# Facebook Open Graph with Two Objects

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I know there is a lot search results for this topic - however I haven't been able to get the answer that I'm looking for.

I have an action, called "Viewed", where the object is a "Picture". The book has a "og:title", however I also want the book to have an Painter - so that post reads:

Greg view a paiting.title by patiner.title on Application.

However - I doesn't appear I can actually assign two objects to a action.

In addition - I've seen numerous situations on Mobile Facebook (app, mobile web), where the full object title is not shown (it just says "viewed a picture"), as if the object doesn't have a title. The object debugger shows the that there is a og:title just fine.

Any suggestions on making this work? I've tried to add a painter object as a property in the "view" action - do I need to include the URL to the painter in the post to get to show up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the structure of the sentences when you define your stories in the Open Graph section of the developer tool.

This allows you to reference any attribute of you object to construct the sentence like in the example below:

[image: Example of story structure]

The way the story is rendered depends on many factors, and in some cases it will render as "viewed a picture" instead of the full title.

Comment: How did you define, taste.beer.brewery? Does that exist as a property in the taste object?

Comment: The reason why I ask this is that if i type "picture." I don't get anything to pop-up.

Comment: The beer is an attribute of the taste object and it's value is the URL of the object beer. The beer object has a string attribute which is called brewery.